# Why @autowired doesn't work on services in the same packages and how to fix it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

In my problem I have two `@Service` components, when I try to inject some of them in my `@RestController` everything is fine but when I want to inject SearchService to TrackService it returns `null`. Does not matter if I inject it by constructor, method or field, it's the same. How I can fix it?

[image]

There is my SearchService class:

```
package pl.mrfisherman.pirate_to_spotify_app.service;

import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import pl.mrfisherman.pirate_to_spotify_app.model.SpotifyTrack;
import pl.mrfisherman.pirate_to_spotify_app.util.UrlConverter;

@Service
public class SearchService {

private static final String SEARCH_ENDPOINT_URL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=";

public SpotifyTrack search(String token, String searchedPhrase, String typeOfSearch, int limitOfResults) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

    HttpEntity<HttpHeaders> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<SpotifyTrack> exchange =
            restTemplate.exchange(UrlConverter.convertStringToURL(
                    SEARCH_ENDPOINT_URL + searchedPhrase
                            + "&type=" + typeOfSearch
                            + "&limit=" + limitOfResults),
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    httpEntity,
                    SpotifyTrack.class);

    return exchange.getBody();
}
}
```

and here is my TrackService:

```
package pl.mrfisherman.pirate_to_spotify_app.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import pl.mrfisherman.pirate_to_spotify_app.model.track.Track;
import pl.mrfisherman.pirate_to_spotify_app.model.track.TrackWrapper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class TrackService {

    public static final String TYPE_OF_SEARCH = "track";

    private final SearchService searchService;

    @Autowired
    public TrackService(SearchService searchService) {
        this.searchService = searchService; //doesn't work
    }

public List<Track> generateTracksDetails(String token, TrackWrapper userTracks) {
    List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<>();

    userTracks.getUserTracks().forEach(userTrack -> {
        searchService.search(token, userTrack.getTitle(), TYPE_OF_SEARCH, 1)
                .getTracks().getItems().stream()
                .map(item -> new Track(
                        item.getId(),
                        item.getName(),
                        item.getArtists().get(0),
                        item.getPreviewUrl(),
                        item.getAlbum().getImages().get(0).getUrl()))
                .forEach(tracks::add);
    });
    return tracks;
}
}
```

Here is my main Class:

```
package pl.mrfisherman.pirate_to_spotify_app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PirateToSpotifyAppApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PirateToSpotifyAppApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share the main class for your Spring boot application? The annotations there might provide useful clues.

Comment: Yes I've just added it.

Comment: so what's the error?

Comment: Null pointer exception for SearchService, when I try to autowire it into TrackService. When I autowire it in RestController everything is ok.

Comment: @MrFisherman that can't be it. `@SpringBootApplication` with `@ComponentScan` should pick up all components under current package. And your null pointer case seems to me that you are not injecting correctly. Mind if you post full src? or relavent packages

Comment: Where are you getting the null pointer exception? Please add the log detail too.

Comment: a spring autowired field cannot be `null`, it it appears `null` the error is on the user side. Either constructing a new instance yourself (outside the scope of Spring), using AOP with final, private or package default methods. See https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/ for a more indepth explanation.